# SQL Server 2008 Update multiple columns with loop or other method

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have two tables: A and B.

Both table contains the exact same layout: ID, Name, Salary, Household

I need to update A's missing records with B.

Table A:

```
ID   NAME   SALARY   HOUSEHOLD
--------------------------------
 1   John     100        2
 2   Jane    NULL        3
 3   Mary     200       NULL
 4   Ann     NULL       NULL
```

Table B:

```
ID   NAME   SALARY   HOUSEHOLD
--------------------------------
 1   John     400        2
 2   Jane     200        3
 3   Mary     200        1
 4   Ann      125        1
```

After all the updates, it should look like this

Table A:

```
ID   NAME   SALARY   HOUSEHOLD
--------------------------------
 1   John     100        2
 2   Jane     200        3
 3   Mary     200        1
 4   Ann      125        1
```

I tried this SQL :

```
UPDATE A
SET SALARY = B.SALARY
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE ISNULL(A.SALARY, '') = ''
  AND ISNULL(B.SALARY, '') <> ''
```

This is my initial update query. I want to be able to update all the columns and basically changing only the column name. If I were to do it manually, I would do the next one like this.

```
UPDATE A
SET HOUSEHOLD = B.HOUSEHOLD
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE ISNULL(A.HOUSEHOLD, '') = ''
  AND ISNULL(B.HOUSEHOLD, '') <> ''
```

I am imagining using a loop that will go to the next variable in some sort of container and use the variable in place for the column name. In my real world table, I have about 30 columns that needed to be updated.

It doesn't have to be a loop. As long as it gets the job done. I would be happy to learn other ways if it makes the job easier!

Perhaps something like this (This is 100% wrong. Not even close to a correct syntax):

```
for i <= 2
i = 1
@Column = ('ID', 'NAME')

UPDATE A
SET @Column = B.@Column
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE ISNULL(A.@Column, '') = ''
  AND ISNULL(B.@Column, '') <> ''
NEXT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Household and salary are numbers, can they really be empty strings? If so, you might consider changing their data types to some kind of numeric.

Anyway you can do this in one shot and with no loops:

```
UPDATE A SET 
  HOUSEHOLD = COALESCE(A.HOUSEHOLD, B.HOUSEHOLD),
  SALARY    = COALESCE(A.SALARY,    B.SALARY)
  -- repeat for other columns
FROM dbo.TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB AS B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME;
```

There may be some desire to only update the rows where there is actually a tangible change, but making one pass and just updating all the matching rows (even those that didn't change) is going to be cheaper than making a separate pass for each change (or for each column).

Comment: I suppose if you wanted to filter for only tangible change you could do a very long WHERE. e.g. `WHERE   (ISNULL(A.HOUSEHOLD, '') = '' AND B.HOUSEHOLD <> '')   OR (ISNULL(A.SALARY, '') = ''
    AND B.SALARY <> '' ) ..` I'm not sure what the relative costs would be .

Comment: @ConradFrix [I've done a bit of testing around this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates), and found that it's usually cheaper to just update rather than bother to check, especially if the matching columns are well indexed (and you don't have 8 billion rows on both sides of the join). Surely there are some edge cases where 99% of the rows are the same but IMHO those are not going to be common (based on the limited sample size it seems like the data is very ragged, and I doubt many rows that are being presented for update will be the same in every single column)

Comment: @ConradFrix At 30 columns I would rather just do some kind of hash, knowing that in the odd case of a collision I'm updating one extra row. I just don't know that even that is worth doing in this case. Presumably you're going to be writing to most of the pages read for the join anyway...

Comment: I don't think this would actually produce the result I wanted though. This will update every records that matches ID and NAME. I want to only update "missing" records when they match ID and NAME. The last two lines of the update query are very important.

Comment: @ColtonPan Why don't you try it with two sample tables? This update yielded exactly the result you stated you wanted in your question.

Comment: @ColtonPan, the `COALESCE` function performs exactly the same test you're doing in your `WHERE` clause. it leaves `TableA` unchanged if there's a value, but inserts the `TableB` value if the column is null. Loops are almost never the answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are so right. I missed that you had COALESCE. I didn't even realize how simple this thing can be. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is a simple but effective loop

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableA TABLE -- temp table to hold data
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        , TableA_ID INT
        ,  [Name] NVARCHAR(256)
        , Salary NVARCHAR(256)
        , HOUSEHOLD INT
    )
    --fill in the temp table with data
    INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT  B.* FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE ISNULL(A.SALARY, '') = ''
AND ISNULL(B.SALARY, '') <> ''
    --declare some variables to hold data
    DECLARE @Count INT, @Counter INT, @TableA_ID INT, @Name NVARCHAR(256),@Salary NVARCHAR(260),@HOUSEHOLD int
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM @TableA m
    SET @Counter = 1


    WHILE @Counter <= @Count
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TableA_ID = TableA_ID, @Name = ModuleTableName,@Salary = Salary,@HOUSEHOLD = HOUSEHOLD
        FROM @TableA m WHERE ID = @Counter


        -- now everything is in variables
        --something like
         --Update TableA set Name = @Name, Salary = @Salary where ID =@TableA_ID

        SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END 
END
```